# How do I add keys recursively to an array

Tags: php, recursion

I have a query result set which I loop through. Depending on the data inside the result set, I want to add it to the array, or if the specific value contains an ID, loop again, and add it at the current position. I want to end up with something like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => Lorem ipsum
                        )
                )
            [uid] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [uid] => Array
                                (
                                    [value] => 1
                                )

                            [field_name] => Array
                                (
                                    [value] => John Doe
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

I accomplished the result, but I'm looping over and over again, I would like it to be recursive. So I ended up doing something like this.

```
foreach ($fields as $nr => $field){
    if ($field_type == 'entity_reference'){
        // Query again
        ... 
        foreach ($fields2 as $nr2 => $field2){
            if ($field_type2 == 'entity_reference'){
                // Query again
                ...
            } else {
                $return[$nr][$field][$nr2][$fieldl2] = $value2;
            }
        }
    } else {
        $return[$nr][$field][] = $value;
    }
}
```

How can I make it recursive, so I don't have to loop many times?

Comment: Have you thought of creating a function, which you then call recursively?

Comment: As to what I understand you need to add value in one of the array element node based on condition. Can you please tell which will be that condition

Comment: The condition would be something like `if ($field_type == 'entity_reference')`. Basically I'm looping through an object off fields, if the field is text, just add it, if the field is a reference (to another object) load it, and add this object. This object goes through the same process, so if this object contains references, I want to add it too. So it's an iterative process of adding objects / arrays.